# Analysis to identify similar occupations by frequency of skills requested in job postings (in R)

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I have access to a dataset of job postings, which for each posting has a unique posting ID, the job posting occupation, and a row for each skill requested in each job posting.

The dataset looks a bit like this:

| posting_id | occ_code | occname | skillname |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | data scientist | analysis |
| 1 | 1 | data scientist | python |
| 2 | 2 | lecturer | teaching |
| 2 | 2 | lecturer | economics |
| 3 | 3 | biologist | research |
| 3 | 3 | biologist | biology |
| 1 | 1 | data scientist | research |
| 1 | 1 | data scientist | R |

I'd like to perform analysis in R to identify "close" occupations by how similar their overall skill demand is in job postings. E.g. if many of the top 10 in-demand skills for financial analysts matched some of the top 10 in-demand skills for data scientists, those could be considered closely related occupations.

To be more clear, I want to identify similar occupations by their overall skill demand in the postings i.e. by summing the no. of times each skill is requested for an occupation, and identifying which other occupations have similar frequently requested skills.

I am fairly new to R so would appreciate any help!

Comment: So what is the expected answer to the example you offered? Explain step by step how you arrived at that expectation. (Unless, that is if you wanted us to offer this question to ChatGPT and get something entirely invented.)

Comment: This might be more suited for https://stats.stackexchange.com/ but needs improvements first. But look at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/384031/how-to-compare-different-clusterings/384075#384075

Answer (score 1):

I think you might want an unsupervised clustering strategy. See the help page for `hclust` for a debugged worked example. This untested code.

```
# Load necessary libraries
library(tidyverse)
library(reshape2)

# Read in the data
data <- read.csv("path/to/your/data.csv")

# Sum the number of times each skill is requested for each occupation
skill_counts <- data %>% 
  group_by(occ_code, occname_skillname) %>% 
  summarise(count = n())

# Get the top 10 in-demand skills for each occupation
top_10_skills <- skill_counts %>% 
  group_by(occ_code) %>% 
  top_n(10, count)

# Convert the data into a matrix for clustering
matrix <- dcast(top_10_skills, occ_code ~ occname_skillname, value.var = "count")

# Perform clustering
fit <- hclust(dist(t(matrix)), method = "ward.D2")

# Plot the dendrogram
plot(fit, hang = -1, labels = row.names(matrix), main = "Occupation Clustering")
```

The resulting dendrogram will show the relationships between the occupations based on their skill demand. Closer occupations will be grouped together and more distantly related occupations will be separated further apart.